# Not able to open remote file into local with Sublime text 3.1.1

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Following [these steps](https://fearby.com/article/how-to-use-sublime-text-editor-locally-to-edit-code-files-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh/) to open remote file in local machine. Able to establish ssh connection and ran `rmate a.txt` or `rsub a.txt` in remote machine but I'm not able to see the file in my local machine.

Tried [rsub](https://github.com/randy3k/RemoteSubl) but I'm not able to. Tried downgrading the Sublime Text version to 2.0.2 even that didn't help.

Can someone suggest me a way to open remote file in local using Sublime Text 3.1.1?

Comment: I can't help with that but I regularly edit remote files in Sublime Text on an [SSHFS mounted drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). If you can `SSH` to the server maybe you can use `SSHFS` to mount the filesytem instead.